# Qt - How to write a FindXXX.cmake file for a certain Qt library

Tags: c++, linux, qt, charts, cmake

So I really want to start developing my Qt project inside a different IDE (Clion to be exact). I've written my CMake file for the project. It successfully finds Qt Core, Widgets and other libraries but when it comes to including Qt Charts Cmake throws an error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package):
>     By not providing "FindQt5Charts.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
>     has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
>     "Qt5Charts", but CMake did not find one.

This error is successfully removed when I add **by hand** a "FindQt5Charts.cmake" file in my CLion>bin>Cmake>share>modules (where FindQt.cmake and othere search package files are) but as of now this file is empty.

The Cmake compiles successfully but since it hasn't found the library I'm looking for, my project won't compile. I need your help to write "FindQt5Charts.cmake" file because I'm not 100% sure of its syntax.

NOTE: Qt Charts is installed and its folder could be found in Qt's installation directory. I just need the code for the FindQt5Charts.cmake.

[Here's a reference to the FindQt.cmake file](https://pastebin.com/Ems1tzSH)

Here is how the beggining of my project's cmake looks:

```
#Pull needed header files generated by QT first
set(QT_GENERATED qtGenerated)
add_custom_target(${QT_GENERATED})

#Get all header files in the directory
file(GLOB QT_GEN_HEADERS ${QT_BIN}/*.h)

#Copy them to the project dir
foreach (QT_GEN_HEADERS ${QT_GEN_HEADERS})
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${QT_GENERATED} PRE_BUILD COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
            ${QT_GEN_HEADERS} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
endforeach ()


# Find the Qt libraries
foreach (QT_LIBRARIES_REQUIRED ${QT_LIBRARIES_REQUIRED})
    find_package(${QT_LIBRARIES_REQUIRED} REQUIRED)
endforeach ()
```

Comment: Description of the file you show clearly states, that it doesn't work with Qt5: `This module can only detect and switch between Qt versions 3 and 4. It cannot handle Qt5 or any later versions.`. Take correct `FindQt5.cmake` script which works with Qt5. As for writting "Find" script by yourself, **complete guide** for that is **too broad**  for Stack Overflow format. You may start with [How To](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Writing_find_modules) on CMake wiki, and ask here about **specific question** you cannot solve.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ah I see. Thank you for the help!